# Member is not recognized or accessible for WPF custom control DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015

Tried on multiple machines, created a new control, which still has the issue, so I'm doing something wrong I'm sure

Here's how I'm using the control:

```
<controls:Pip Text="1" Color="Blue" />
```

The properties show up in the suggested properties list, but are marked as not recognized or accessible.

Designer refuses to display it, but it works... compiles and runs without issue

I've tried common solutions posted in threads here: cleared the cache, clean and rebuild, set to AnyCPU build

Class for the control:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Pip.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Pip : UserControl {
        /// <summary>
        /// Register the Text property of the control
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Text", typeof(string), typeof(Pip), new PropertyMetadata("#"));
        public string Text {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Register the Color property of the control
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Color", typeof(Color), typeof(Pip), new PropertyMetadata(Colors.Blue));
        public Color Color {
            get { return (Color)GetValue(ColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ColorProperty, value); }
        }

        public Pip() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

XAML for it:

```
<UserControl x:Class="testing.Controls.Pip" x:Name="pip"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:gbtis.Controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             Height="30" Width="30">
    <UserControl.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=Color, ElementName=pip, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </UserControl.Background>
    <Viewbox>
        <Border>
            <TextBlock Padding="5" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=pip, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                <TextBlock.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="2" Direction="0" ShadowDepth="0"/>
                </TextBlock.Effect>
            </TextBlock>
        </Border>
    </Viewbox>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: It's just the XAML designer being a punk. If it compiles and runs without issue, ignore it.

Comment: And remove `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` from all the Bindings. It makes absolutely no sense here.

Comment: Do I need something instead, or will it update anyway?

Comment: If I can change the topic for a minute... I guess I just can't use the designer anymore? There's no fix?

Comment: @user1456632 Why do you have the Color property at all, when you could as well directly set the control's Background, like `<controls:Pip Text="1" Background="Blue">`?

Comment: I've since removed it, but I still need the text one

Comment: With VS2019: I had some UserControls with values assigned to DataContext. It was a mistake. The same incomprehensible error was shown for about any DP used, this prevented me to compile. I searched for hours in wrong directions, until I noticed the DataContext leftovers. After I removed all assignments, this was gone.